# How to integrate $ \iint_S \ln(1+x+y)\ dx dy$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate 
$$
\iint_{S} \ln(1+x+y)\ dxdy$$
where $S\subset{\bf R}^2$ is given by
 $$
S=\{(x,y)\mid x\geq 0,y> 0;x+y\leq 1\}.
$$

---

I define 
$$
0\leq x\leq 1-y;\quad y\in\, ]0,1],$$ but then i get something tough like this:
$$
\int_{0}^{1-y}{}([(1+x)\ln(1+x)-(1+x)]-(2+x)\ln(2+x)-(2+x))dx$$ I think there is an error here, how to integrate this?

Comment: The integration is on S,a surface in $R^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _0^1\int _0^{1-x}\log (x+y+1)\,dy\,dx=$$
$$=\int_0^1 \left[x-(x+1) \log (x+1)-1+\log 4\right] \, dx=$$
$$=\left.\frac{3 x^2}{4}-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log (x+1)-\frac{x}{2}+x \log (4)-x \log (x+1)-\frac{1}{2} \log (x+1)\right|_0^1=\frac14$$

Hope this helps

Comment: Why can I integrate from 0 when y is not set to 0?

Comment: The primitive is $(x+y+1) \log (x+y+1)-y+C$ it makes no difference taking the integral with or without the $0$.